# Selecting multiple coded values for domains

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains, arcgis-collector

Is it possible to setup a domain that allows for the selection of multiple coded values? I have setup an app that allows field staff to do inspections at various field sites by asking them preset questions. The problem is that for some questions there is often multiple answers.

For example, one question asks for the type of material used for structural foundations. In a lot of cases there is only one type used (concrete, wood etc...), however in some cases there maybe multiple foundation types.

Is there anyway to allow for the selection of two (or more) answers for coded value domains?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with collector, however some form design applications have additional parameters for the various controls (e.g. combo box) that you can enable multi selection.

Beyond that, you may have to write a custom event listener on control value selection that writes that value to another field.  Each time the value is selected an additional value will be appended to the field (e.g. concrete, wood, steel).  Usually this control is a large text box in the form that the user can see and interact with (e.g. select and delete values).

Comment: I believe the combo-box or check-box would be custom code, if you are able to do it within collector (unless something has changed within Collector in the last few months), but this could be a possibility if you have the time/patience/skill :)

Answer (score 1):

Two domains cannot be added to a single column.

If you have combinations that are common, you can code those domains as such (Concrete & Wood, for example).  You could also set up a column with the same coded values as a secondary material.

> PrimaryMaterial: Concrete
>
> SecondaryMaterial: Wood

I would strongly suggest not allowing write-in values that would allow multiple values/variations per column. This will become your worst nightmare when needing to query something out at a later date.

Comment: Your suggestion of multiple fields does work, although in the event that there a numerous materials used, the form could end up getting VERY long. I suspect that it may be an issue we may just have to deal with.